# Open url with relative path

Tags: java, url, web-crawler, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to extract links from a website:

```
String domain_url = "http://www.example.com";
Document doc;

doc = Jsoup.connect(domain_url)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)")
    .timeout(5000)
    .get();

Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
for (Element link : links)
{
    String link_href = link.attr("href");
    System.out.println(link_href);
}
```

When an absolute url appears:

```
http://www.example.com/blog
```

There is no problem to call this url.
But how to open a relative link?

```
/blog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the link href with this:

```
String link_href = link.absUrl("href");
```

This will give you an absolute url you can use.